Crystal reports highlighting
I have a field in a Crystal Report that I want to highlight based on multiple Criteria.
I cannot figure out a way to get a switch and/or if statement to work for me.
This is for a productivity report. There are 2 ways to get productivity: without adjustments or with adjustments.
My purpose, if it helps, is to highlight in Yellow if the number is in a certain range. It tells the user to look at this person's score because they are very close to getting the next non-adjusted bonus level. When highlighted in orange then it will indicate they are very close to the next adjusted bonus level (it adjusts for any time off they had and reduces the score they must get to be eligible for bonus but also reduces the bonus).
Any help Appreciated!
So the code highlights in yellow first, if needed, but then highlights in orange, if needed, regardless of whether it was highlighted in yellow or not.
Note the reason I do the else NocrColor is because it would highlight in black for some reason.
The first code below checks the non-adjusted.
I want to run the following code no matter what:
IF ISNULL({Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) or {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits} = 0 THEN 
if (({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 18000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} 
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 17500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency}) 
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 16000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} 
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 15500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency}) 
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 14500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency}
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 14000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency})) 
    then crYellow
else crNoColor
ELSE //ISNULL({Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) is false and {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits} <> 0
if (({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 18000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 17500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100))
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 16000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 15500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100))
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 14500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 14000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)))
    then crYellow
else crNoColor

But then I also want to run the following code for adjusted bonus but only if Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} <> 1:
IF ISNULL({Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) or {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits} = 0 THEN 
if (({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 18000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} 
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 17500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent}) 
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 16000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent}  
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 15500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent}) 
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 14500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} 
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 14000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent})) 
    then color(245, 176, 65)
else crNoColor
ELSE 
if (({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 18000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 17500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100))
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 16000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 15500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100))
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 14500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 14000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)))
    then color(245, 176, 65)
else crNoColor


I found the answer on another stack overflow question:
The simplest way to do this with the code you have is wrapping the if blocks in parentheses and separating them with semicolons:
Crystal Report: How to evaluate multiple IF statements in one formula?
(IF ISNULL({Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) or {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits} = 0 THEN 
if (({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 18000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} 
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 17500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency}) 
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 16000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} 
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 15500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency}) 
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 14500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency}
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 14000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency})) 
    then crYellow
else crNoColor
ELSE //ISNULL({Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) is false and {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits} <> 0
if (({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 18000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 17500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100))
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 16000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 15500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100))
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 14500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 14000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)))
    then crYellow
else crNoColor
);

(if  {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} <> 1 then
IF ISNULL({Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) or {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits} = 0 THEN 
if (({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 18000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} 
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 17500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent}) 
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 16000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent}  
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 15500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent}) 
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 14500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} 
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 14000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent})) 
    then color(245, 176, 65)
else crNoColor
ELSE 
if (({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 18000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 17500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100))
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 16000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 15500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100))
or ({Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} < 14500 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)
and {Productivity_Bonuses.Revenue} >= 14000 * {MPC_OPData.FullTime_Equivalency} * {Productivity_Bonuses.Bonus_Percent} * ((100 - {Productivity_Bonuses.Credits}) / 100)))
    then color(245, 176, 65)
else crNoColor
);

